# What is the event which raise when a processes comes up

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to act with a service (kill the procces) whenever a process (executable file) comes up. 
Obviusly it is an Event but I don't know what event is.
Is there someone to assist me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event raised when a process starts. The best you can do is poll using [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx) - here's a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ProcessNotify.aspx) about doing so.

Comment: That may be very close to what i need but is in C++ and I really don't know anything about it, is there any code in C# or vb.net?

Comment: Please tell me this: this code produce a class which aware all the time in my system processes? Or it works only once?

Comment: @Lefteris Gkinis, it works by polling. You tell it how often you want it to enumerate the processes. That's described at the top of the first page, in the `Using the Code` section.