# Keeping a list of processes

Tags: list, windows-7, process

Here is my scenario: I have a function which performs operations on other processes. It performs an operation on a given process, then performs some more operations, then undoes the first operation. I would like to do this operation only once on each process.

This leads to my question: How do I keep a list of processes to identify which ones have already been operated on and which have not? I was thinking of storing process ids, but they are recyclable. Process handles are also recyclable.

Answer (score 1):

If you hold on to the handle, the process object cannot be destroyed and the PID will not be re-used.

Once the process has quit, which you can find out by Waiting on the handle, you can close the handle. Only then will the PID be re-used, but since you know the process has quit you can be sure that any recurrence is a different process.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it is acceptable to use process time as a means of identifying processes for my purpose. If anyone would like to know how, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291341/what-is-the-event-which-raise-when-a-processes-comes-up/5291535#5291535), and the links there in my answer. One of them discusses [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223%28VS.85%29.aspx), which will give you the time the process started.